# Bookmarks hierarchy with custom titleclass

Tags: hyperref, pdf, titlesec, bookmarks

I'm new here, but I've been using LaTeX for some years already.

Recently I had to define new chapter- and section-like levels in my document, and I created them using the `titlesec` package, with the `titleclass` command. For a correct formatting in the TOC I used `titletoc` (`titlecontents` command).

```latex
\titleclass{\fase}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{fase}
\titleformat{\fase}{\centering\sffamily\huge\bfseries}{}{0em}{FASE \thefase\\ }
\titlespacing*{\fase}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1cm}
\titlecontents{fase}[0pt]{\vspace{1em}}{\bfseries Fase\ \thecontentslabel : }{}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}


\titleclass{\tarea}{straight}[\fase]
\newcounter{tarea}[fase]
\titleformat{\tarea}{\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries}{TAREA \thefase.\thetarea: }{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\tarea}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlecontents{tarea}[1.5em]{}{Tarea\ \thecontentslabel : }{}{\ \hfill\contentspage}
```

The thing is that it does not respect the levels in the pdf bookmarks. In Overleaf, `hyperref` throws a warning saying that the level is unknown for `tarea` and it sets it to 0, so I guess there must be a way to set the level for this section-like command. But nothing appears in my local distribution (texlive for windows)

To show what I mean, here's a screenshot:

[image]

So 'Introducción' was created with `\chapter`, 'Objetivos', 'Herramientas a utilizar' y 'Zona de trabajo' with `\section`.

Now, 'Sistema de separación' and 'Sistema ARQUIMEA' are `\fase`, and the rest are `\tarea` (fase = phase, tarea = task)

I looked online, but none of the solutions that I found deal with exactly the same problem, so their solutions didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain your issue better, for example with adding a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue?